# Django Wagtail CMS slugurl and pageurl not working - link returns 'None'

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, wagtail

I am building my third Wagtail CMS site (v.1.8) but have never been able to figure out the `slugurl` & `pageurl` tags to create internal links and have just hardcoded all the links, even though hardcoding goes against the grain in my workflow.  Can someone please help me out. And yes, I did add `{% load wagtailcore_tags %}` to my page.

For demonstration purposes, I am going to use a very simple model that is going to give my client a template with just a title and a body as one of their page templates.  The page is aptly called `StandardPage(Page)` and a template named `standard_page.html`.  I created an `about` page and want to provide a link to the page in my header and footer. I know I can hardcode it; but that is not what I would to do.

I have tried `{% slugurl page.about %}` but link returns `None` - I even tried `{% slugurl standardpage.about %}` thinking I was missing something but of course it returns `None` as well.

I always used named routes in all my Django projects and not being able to figure this out is driving me crazy.

Here is my model for reference. Thank you.

```
class StandardPage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('title'),
        index.SearchField('body'),
    ]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Standard Page - No Image Placement'

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
    ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{% slugurl page.about %}` would look for a field called `about` on your current page - this fails because there's no field with that name.

If you want to link to the page with the slug 'about', use `{% slugurl 'about' %}`. (However, you should realise that this really isn't much different from hard-coding the URL... if you're worried about hard-coding because an editor might accidentally rename the page and break the link, then `slugurl` won't protect you against that. Ultimately you have to trust your editors not to do anything silly!)

Comment: That worked.  I understand that `slugurl` isn't any different then hardcoding, but I am used to using url tags and using it will at least satisfy my OCD :) Thank you.